# sumar booleanos en dataframe con groupby

Tags: python, pandas, count

Buen dia, estoy realizando una actividad para aprender python, peor me encuentro atascado.

El DataFrame que retorna la función tiene que tener una fila por cada
modelo. El DataFrame tendrá 7 columnas: CANTIDAD, que tendrá un número
entero con la cantidad de descargas que haya tenido el modelo; PROMEDIO,
que tendrá un número decimal con la cantidad promedio que se pagó por
el modelo; MAXIMO que tendrá un número decimal con la cantidad máxima
que se pagó por el modelo; MINIMO que tendrá un número decimal con la
cantidad mínima que se pagó por el modelo; ESTRELLAS, que tendrá un
número decimal con la cantidad promedio de estrellas que se le dio al
modelo; DESV. ESTRELLAS, que tendrá un número decimal con la desviación
estándar de la cantidad de estrellas que se le hayan dado al modelo; y
COMENTARIOS, que tendrá un número entero con la cantidad de comentarios
que hayan dejado los compradores.
tengo la siguiente informacion:
Notas importantes sobre el DataFrame resultado:

El índice del DataFrame tendrá los nombres de los modelos y sólo
deben aparecer aquellos para los que al menos un usuario haya pagado. Es
decir que no deben aparecer los modelos que hayan sido siempre
gratuitos.
Los modelos deben aparecer en orden alfabético de acuerdo a su nombre.
Todos los números que no sean enteros deben aparecer redondeados a dos cifras decimales.
Como la desviación estándar no se puede calcular cuando haya
sólo un dato, en lugar de NaN debe aparecer 0.0 en el resultado.

[image: dataframe]

en esta ocasión necesito contar el numero de booleanos TRUE que podría tener cada modelo. quedando una solucion asi:

[image: solucion_deseada]

no estoy haciendo un uso adecuado del ciclo for para hacer conteo del mismo, existe alguna otra posibilidad? a continuación presento mi código

```
import pandas as pd
def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:pd.DataFrame)->pd.DataFrame:
    pagado=descargas[descargas['PAGO']>0]

    numero_comentarios = []

    for modelo in range(0,len(pagado)):
        conteo=0
        if pagado['COMENTARIO'][modelo]==True:
            conteo = 1
        else:
            conteo = 0
        numero_comentarios.append(conteo)

    pagado['COMENTARIOS'] = numero_comentarios
    sorteado = pagado.groupby('MODELO')
    sumar_comentarios = sorteado['COMENTARIOS'].sum()
    
    contar_usuarios = sorteado['PAGO'].count()
    pago_promedio = sorteado['PAGO'].mean()
    pago_max = sorteado['PAGO'].max()
    pago_min = sorteado['PAGO'].min()
    promedio_estrellas = sorteado['ESTRELLAS'].mean()
    desv_estrellas = sorteado['ESTRELLAS'].std()


    df={}
    df['CANTIDAD'] = contar_usuarios
    df['PROMEDIO'] = round(pago_promedio,2)
    df['MAXIMO'] = round(pago_max,2)
    df['MINIMO'] = round(pago_min,2)
    df['ESTRELLAS'] = round(promedio_estrellas,2)
    df['DESV. ESTRELLAS'] = round(desv_estrellas,2)
    df['COMENTARIOS'] = sumar_comentarios

    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
    

    data_frame['DESV. ESTRELLAS'] = data_frame['DESV. ESTRELLAS'].fillna(0)
    data_frame.fillna(0)
    return data_frame
```

haciendo uso del .count obtengo el siguiente error: [image: error]

Comment: Nose para que haces un for ni para que vuelves a construir un DataFrame, lo único que necesitas es el `groupby`

Comment: he intentado hacer uso del groupby, pero no logro hacer que cuente explicitamente el TRUE, tambien me cuenta los FALSE

Comment: entonces usa `.count("contar")` donde le pasas como parámetro en base a que vas a contar

Comment: podrias colocar los datos en la pregunta??

Comment: Todo lo que tengo son esas dos imágenes pues debo crear el codigo a partir de eso y la  pagina evalúa la función por si misma. en otras palabras ni siquiera yo tengo acceso a los datos

Comment: ._. dificultas el trabajo, haré algo con datos inventados y te daré una respuesta

Comment: pido disculpas, de antemano agradezco tu ayuda. he actualizado el codigo haciendo uso del .count y estoy obteniendo el error que muestro en la pregunta

Comment: necesitas obtener las columnas `promedio`, `maximo`, etc o solo te interesa contar los comentario??

Comment: He agregado a la pregunta la informacion del dataframe de retorno que debo obtener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final creo que es mas fácil obtener los datos por separados, al agruparlos puedes acceder a métodos como `.count()`,`.mean()`,`.sum()`,`.max()`, etc. Pero solo uno por cada agrupación, por lo que no puedes hacer `df.mean().sum().max()` ya que esas operaciones se irán aplicando de forma consecutiva, y como nos piden diferentes medidas para cada campo mejor es agrupar el *DataFrame* y luego crear las variables correspondientes para cada campo.

```py
#cree mi propio DF
cols = ["modelo","usuario","Pago","estrellas","Comentario"]
data = [
        ["Bus urbano","ted mobys",24.99,5,True],
        ["carrito","christian",12,3.5,False],
        ["piano","michael",0,4,False],
        ["piano","otro wey",0,4.5,False],
        ["Bus urbano","ted mobys",20,2,True]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
```

Una forma que se me ocurrió de poder contar solo los valores `True` fue cambiándolos por su valor en binario, `1` es `true` y `0` es `False`. Para hacer eso usamos el método `.apply()` para aplicarle *una conversión*. Para hacer eso podemos hacer la condición `1 if str(x) == "True" else 0` donde hacemos uso de la sintaxis de *operador ternario* donde será 1 si el valor de `x` (convertido a string) es `True` de lo contrario será `0`, pero podemos reducir esto a `int(x)`. Al convertir un booleano a entero nos regresa `1` o `0` según sea `True` o `False`. Esto es de gran ayuda ya que pandas infiere el tipo de dato, pero ten cuidado. Si no estas seguro utiliza la primera forma

```py
#cambiamos los valores de la columna a 0 ó 1
df["Comentario"] = df["Comentario"].apply(lambda x: int(x)) #1 if str(x)=="True" else 0
```

Hago la conversión a `0` o `1` para luego sumar todo al hacer el `groupby()` para que así solo haya contabilización de los valores `True`.

Ahora tenemos que realizar la agrupación de los datos y luego extraer cada una de las operaciones que nos piden (promedio -> `mean()`, maximo->`max()`, cantidad->`count()`) y luego transformamos los datos a listas para luego crear un nuevo DataFrame.

```py
#agrupamos los datos
grupo = df.groupby("modelo")

#obtenemos los datos
count_comentarios = grupo["Comentario"].sum().to_list() #contabilizacion de comentariso True
cantidad = grupo["Comentario"].count().to_list() #cantidad
prom = grupo[["Pago","estrellas"]].mean() #promedio de Pago y estrellas, no se convierte a lista
min,max =  grupo["Pago"].min().to_list(), grupo["Pago"].max().to_list() #minimos y maximos
```

No convertimos a lista la variable `prom` dado que al sacar el promedio `.mean()` de mas de una columna, el resultado es un DataFrame y no una Serie como los otros.

Ahora necesitamos crear un nuevo DataFrame con los nuevos valores, para eso vamos a usar a los diccionarios como estructuras base del nuevo *DF*. Pero antes hay que obtener los índices del anterior *DF*, por suerte tenemos a nuestra variable `prom` el cual es una *DataFrame* por lo que podemos obtener sus índices.

```py
#obtenemos los indices y los metemos en una lista
indexs = [ind for ind in prom.index]
#creamos el diccionario donde la llave es el nombre de la columna y el valor es la lista
new_data = {"Cantidad":cantidad,"Comentarios":count_comentarios,"Minimo":min,"Maximo":max}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data,index=indexs) #creamos el nuevo DF
new_df["Pago"] = prom["Pago"] #agregamos la columna pago a partir del anterior df
new_df["Estrellas"] = prom["estrellas"] #agregamos la columna estrellas a partir del anterior df

print(new_df)
```

**resultado**

|  | Cantidad | Comentarios | Minimo | Maximo | Pago | Estrellas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bus urbano | 2 | 2 | 20.0 | 24.99 | 22.495 | 3.50 |
| carrito | 1 | 0 | 12.0 | 12.00 | 12.000 | 3.50 |
| piano | 2 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.00 | 0.000 | 4.25 |

Creo que la explicación fue bastante amplia y buena y ya tienes la mayoría de los datos, así que te dejo a ti calcular la columna de `Desviación estándar`, buena suerte :D.